# How do I use Stack in singly linked list

Tags: singly-linked-list

I have a program that asks for 5 inputs and asks for a range. The ranges are in singly linked list. Now, if the 5 inputs are in that range, I have to stack push them to that node(range). So it will look like this for example:

```
range: 20 //max is 99. so it divides 99. for example: 0-19   20-39   40-59 and so on...

 [15]                     [50]
   |                       |
   v                       v
  [1]         [21]        [41]   //5 inputs stack pushed to the ranges.
   |           |           |
   v           V           v
[0-19]----->[20-39]----->[40-59]
/range1     range2       range3
```

Now my problem is. How do i push the 5 input numbers to the list? Can i connect 
two nodes to one node? Or do i break the ranges and push/connect the inputs to the ranges?

Answer (score 0):

This seems more like a problem solved best by a sorted list instead of a stack or several stacks. Why is it that you need to use stacks?

Comment: Sorted list? Stack to push the inputs to that ranges. I do not get the algorithm on how to do that.

Comment: The range are inputted by the user. So if the user inputs range is 10. So i will have 10 ranges. 0-9 10-19 .... So i will have many stack?

Comment: I think you would have to have a list of ranges. If the range needed is not found add a new node to the list. Then each range node will hold a stack and a reference to the top node of the stack. The ranges list would be a sorted list.

Comment: while (numberOfNodesInList < numberOfRanges) addNewListNode();

Comment: Or since you know the number of ranges you can have an array of stacks.